# How to keep track of history in Wicket?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

When using `setResponsePage(Somepage.class)` or `setResponsePage(new Somepage())` I want to know the page where the setResponsePage(...) is called from in the Page I'm going to.

setResponsePage in Component is final so I can't override it.

I don't want to set the current page in the next one manually like so:

```
Page page = new Somepage();
page.setReturnPage(new Returnable() {
    @Override
    public BasePage onReturn() {
        // use some local final variable to create a new instance of this previous page
    }
});
setResponsePage(page);
```

I just want it to be available. I do want to be able to manually change the "returnpage" if I want.

I tried to keep track of this using the Session but that didn't work.

I'm currently trying to figure out if this is possible using an IRequestCycleListener but I can't determine the Page I'm coming from in the RequestCycle.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can design your page to take a `PageReference` argument in its constructor. Every Page descendant has `getPageReference()` method to return this for you.

```
public SomePage(PageReference pageRef) {
    this.pageRef = pageRef;
}
```

Then when you need to return to the previous page you can simply call

```
setResponsePage(this.pageRef.getPage());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your solutions is better than the example I gave in my  question. It forces the user to add a PageReference to a new page and make the reference available in every page. I'm trying to do exactly that, but automatically. I don't want to add the reference in each link in my source. Using the constructor for this is not a bad idea though.